# Table Tree in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to make tree table in angular 2 using jquery-treegrid.
1. I added a jquery-treegrid dependency on package.json.
2. Install typescript jquery library:
    tsd install jquery
3. add html code:

```
  <table class="tree">
    <tr class="treegrid-1">
      <td>Root node</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
      <td>Node 1-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1">
      <td>Node 1-2</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-3">
      <td>Node 1-2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

My Component Class:

```
declare var jQuery:any;
@Component({
  selector: '[configuration]',
  template: require('./configuration.html'),
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('./configuration.scss')],
  directives: [Widget, TablesBackgrid, DataTableDirectives],
  providers: [ConfigurationService,
              HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  pipes: [SearchPipe]
})
export class Configuration implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  data: ISystem[];
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService, private rootNode: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(this.rootNode.nativeElement.find('.tree')[0]).treegrid();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configurationService.getSystems()
      .subscribe(systems => this.data = systems,
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

}
```

Errors in console:

```
TypeError: this.rootNode.nativeElement.find is not a function
```

I following answers on this forum and it didn't work.
Are some others plugins to run table tree in angular2?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
jQuery(this.rootNode.nativeElement).find('.tree')[0].treegrid();
```

(moved `)`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are issues with your code. You are trying to bind a jQuery method to a DOM Element and that is not available for them but for jQuery objects. So, you can change to this:

```
jQuery(this.rootNode.nativeElement).find('.tree').first().treegrid();
```

As you mentioned you are using jQuery treegrid and i suppost it needs a jQuery object so you have to remove the `[0]` because it converts the jQ object back to DOM Element, Instead you can use `.first()` to get the first element of class `.tree`.